# Load AJAX function value dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to insert a list of string dynamically created from an AJAX call. This is the function:

```
function finIngredients(boxId, prodid) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/Products/GetBoxIngredientsNew?idbox=" + boxId,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data != "error") {
                            var element =
                            $('<li> ' + item[0] + '<span class="new-text-Intro"> (' + item[1] + ' kg)</span> OMAGGIO</li>');
                            $("#ingredients").append(element);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This function works fine and returns the correct value. I must insert the result of this function into the `<ul>` tag "ingredients":

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <h2 class="SottotitoloNostriBox">@item.ProductCartDesc</h2>
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
         <ul class="new-text-Intro2" style="min-height: 154px;" id="ingredients"  ondblclick="trovaIngredients(@item.ProductId,@item.ProductId);"></ul>
      </div>
   }
```

The problem is that I want to insert the value of functions for each element when I load it. This code works fine but only when I double-click on each element.

Comment: i cant see item, where is item defined...e.g. item[0] + '<span class="new-text-Intro">

Comment: also its ondblclick not onclick fyi

Comment: also its odd that you have the click event on the ul element

Comment: i have removed some row of code but it works fine. My problem is how to visualize the informations, if in the ul or in another object and how to load the result of function finIngredients. I don't understand how to do it if i have the @foreach (var item in Model) structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the code works when you click on the element, it sounds like you've put your function in an "onclick" event,

Just try calling your function in a "document ready" event after your function definition:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = ...
    var b = ...
    finIngredients(a,b);
});
```

Comment: up voted took me a while to work out what he was on about.

Comment: I don't understand how to do it if i have the @foreach (var item in Model) structure

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean. Try removing the ondblclick section and just adding this code inside the foreach loop; `<script>$(document).ready(function(){ trovaIngredients(@item.ProductId,@item.ProductId); });</script>` not the prettiest solution, but it should be the simplest way to get it to work with your config. Add the script element inside the foreach after the div

Answer (score 0):

PS this is just to show you how you could use Model....

```
<ul class="new-text-Intro2" id="ingredients">
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
      <li>@item.ProductCartDesc</li>
   }
</ul>
```

Comment: But i have a different list of ingredients for each value in the model and not a list of ingredients for alla object. I need to visualize the ingredients information for each element

Comment: please add the code for Model... i.e. what you are returning from the controller.

Comment: I return the li tag from JavaScript function

Comment: please just add more code. I can see that.how many times do you call finIngredients and where from?